# How do susceptible organisms prevent parasites from overcoming resistance?

Tags: ecology, population-biology, community-ecology, parasitism

Bt corn is genetically modified to kill borers, but "regulations require farmers to plant conventional varieties as well, which is intended to stop the borers becoming resistant."
-[Source](http://www.bbc.co.uk/news/science-environment-11496710)

How do susceptible organisms prevent parasites from overcoming host resistance?

Answer (score 4):

In an environment where all plants are resistant to certain parasites, a rare breed which has a mechanism against this resistance has free play - lots of food and no competition. However, in plants which do not have the resistance, this rare parasite breed may be at a disadvantage compared to parasites who do not have the mechanism against that resistance (even if only because they do not waste energy on a defensive mechanism they don't need).

By mixing resistant and unresistant plants, it is probably possible to maintain high enough a competition of parasites without that defensive mechanism to prevent the ones with the mechanism from developing. It's natural selection at work :)